# I Need To Know How To Add Space In A FlowLayout

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, space, flowlayout

I would like to add some space between the JTextField and the JButtons, i am using a flow layout, and help would be appreciated

The text field and the buttons are to close, any input would help, i am a newb

I am making a calculator

CODE

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class Ken {

static JTextField text = new JTextField("0",9);



public static void frame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyCalc");
    frame.setSize(480, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(0, 30, 20);
    setLayout(fl);

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(fl);
    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    Font f = new Font("MS UI Gothic", Font.BOLD, 40);
    Font f2 = new Font("Engravers MT", Font.PLAIN, 40);
    int bHeight = 80;
    int bWidth = 70;
    text.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    text.setFont(f2);
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));




    frame.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JButton oneButton = new JButton("1");
    oneButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    oneButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    oneButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    oneButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(oneButton);

    JButton twoButton = new JButton("2");
    twoButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    twoButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    twoButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    twoButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(twoButton);

    JButton threeButton = new JButton("3");
    threeButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    threeButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    threeButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    threeButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(threeButton);

    JButton plusButton = new JButton("+");
    plusButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    plusButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    plusButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    plusButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(plusButton);

    JButton fourButton = new JButton("4");
    fourButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    fourButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    fourButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    fourButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(fourButton);

    JButton fiveButton = new JButton("5");
    fiveButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    fiveButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    fiveButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    fiveButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(fiveButton);

    JButton sixButton = new JButton("6");
    sixButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    sixButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    sixButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    sixButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(sixButton);

    JButton minusButton = new JButton("-");
    minusButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    minusButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    minusButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    minusButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(minusButton);

    JButton sevenButton = new JButton("7");
    sevenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    sevenButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    sevenButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    sevenButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(sevenButton);

    JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
    eightButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    eightButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    eightButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    eightButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(eightButton);

    JButton nineButton = new JButton("9");
    nineButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight,bWidth));
    nineButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    nineButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    nineButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(nineButton);

    JButton timesButton = new JButton("*");
    timesButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    timesButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    timesButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    timesButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(timesButton);

    JButton zeroButton = new JButton("0");
    zeroButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    zeroButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    zeroButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    zeroButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(zeroButton);

    JButton enterButton = new JButton("=");
    enterButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, bWidth));
    enterButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    enterButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    enterButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(enterButton);

    JButton dividButton = new JButton("/");
    dividButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    dividButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    dividButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    dividButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(dividButton);

    frame.setComponentOrientation(
            ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
}



private static Dimension Dimension(int bHeight, int bWidth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}



private static void setLayout(FlowLayout fl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public static void main(String[] args){
    frame();
}
 }
```

Comment: Why does your code still have the `setPreferredSize()` statement along with the other statements to set the width/heigt variables???

Comment: @camickr i fixed my issue by changing the parameters of static JTextField text = new JTextField("0",9);

Comment: That is my point. The other code does nothing and is not necessary ... get rid of it!!!

Comment: New user name? [why-are-my-buttons-taking-up-the-whole-jframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261699/why-are-my-buttons-taking-up-the-whole-jframe). You still haven't accepted any answers from previous questions. And it's not my answer that concerns me. It's all your other questions. Please fix this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, i did not know you could accept answers, that account got, like, banned

Comment: And again, you're much better off not using FlowLayout as I explained in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17261724/522444).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(0, 30, 20);

Not related to this question, but don't use magic numbers. I have no idea what the 0 means. Read the FlowLaout API and use the proper variable name provide by the API.

By default a the content pane of the frame uses a BorderLayout. Check our the `BorderLayout` API. You can specify the gap size between components. So you can create a new BorderLayout with the desired gap and then set the layout for the content pane to this BorderLayout.

Or, you can add an `EmptyBorder` to the top panel. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.